# geom_map all subregions the same color

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I'm attempting to move over from older ways of mapping data to a choropleth now that ggplot2 has the geom_map.  An example is seen on pp. 10-11 ([HERE](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf)).

I'm attempting to do this with a data set I've created a choropleth from in the past just not with ggplot's new geom_map.  Here's my attempt that I think is like Hadely's example but everything is the same color.

The data set and code:

```
#loads 2 data frames: ny and cad from my drop box
load(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/MAPPING.RData"))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cad, aes(map_id = subregion)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = Math_Pass_Rate), map = ny) +
    expand_limits(x = ny$long, y = ny$lat) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(colours = topo.colors(10))) +
    opts(legend.position = "top")
```

Why is it showing up as the same color?

---

Additional information from @PaulHiemstra

I've puzzling a bit on it, and could not get a good result. However, I also wonder why the example from the ggplot2 pdf you link to works.

This code produces a correct choropleth map.

```
crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
states_map <- map_data("state")
ggplot(crimes, aes(map_id = state)) +
   geom_map(aes(fill = Murder), map = states_map) +
   expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
   guides(fill = guide_colorbar(colours = topo.colors(10))) +
   opts(legend.position = "top")
```

One would expect that by using `map_id = state`, that a link was made between a column in `states_map` (the polygons) and a column in `crimes` (`Murder`). `crimes` contains a `state` column:

```
> head(crimes)
                state Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama       alabama   13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska         alaska   10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       arizona    8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas     arkansas    8.8     190       50 19.5
California california    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado     colorado    7.9     204       78 38.7
```

but `states_map` does not:

```
> head(states_map)
       long      lat group order  region subregion
1 -87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>
2 -87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>
3 -87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>
4 -87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>
5 -87.57087 30.32665     1     5 alabama      <NA>
6 -87.58806 30.32665     1     6 alabama      <NA>
```

So in the link between the polygons and the data, some black magic seems to be happening. This might also explain the problems @TylerRinker has.

Comment: +1, interesting use of dropbox.

Comment: I added some more strange behavior to the question. I could not figure out why the example even worked.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra One interesting side note: I couldn't seem to get `x <- readRDS("foo.rds")` to work in the same way, as I generally like the way you can control your work space better with `readRDS` because you dictate the object names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behavior of `geom_map`. `geom_map` always draws the `region` variable (or alternatively `id`) from `states_map`. This is confirmed by the following. Running:

```
ny$region = ny$subregion
```

puts the `subregion` names into the `region` column. Now plotting leads to the correct image:

[image]

So, `geom_map` uses the `region` or `id`.

Comment: I created a bug report on the `ggplot2` github for this issue. https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/504

Comment: I don't think this is a bug - the `map_id` names the matching variable in the data data frame, not the map data frame.  As documented, that must always be called `id` or `region`

Comment: Thank you so much for help with this Paul.  This one required some digging.  I've wanted to make the switch for a while because Hadley's new implementation doesn't treat the filling as categorical as I've had to do in the past with binning data and creating an artificial factor.  This makes my heart very happy.

Comment: Good too hear that this fixed your problem. I should have RTFM before complaining to @hadley :).